# What is the motivation for Compiler Warning C4806 (number==bool value)?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

Why is `true==151` regarded as unsafe operation while `true==true`, which is virtually holding the same expression, isn't. Moreover, why can `true==151` never be true, unlike `true&&151`?

```
cout<<(true==151);      //0 and it gives compiler warning C4806
cout<<(true==true);     //1 no warning
if(true==151)cout<<"1"; //"0" and warning again
if(true&&151)cout<<"1"; //1 no warning
if(151)cout<<"1";       //1
```

The warning C4806 itself

> '==': unsafe operation: no value of type 'bool' promoted to type 'int' can equal the given constant

Comment: It's a good idea to include the entire message and not just its code. Believe it or not, but many of us haven't committed all Microsoft's error codes to memory.

Comment: Different types. Is true yellow?

Comment: @ZDF Does truth have a colour?

Comment: @molbdnilo :) Is yellow true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First let's answer your second question:  `true==151` is always false because `true` is defined to have the value `1`.

*In general* if you interpret a numeric value as a boolean, 0 will be false and anything else will be true; but the literal `true` has to have a specific value, and that value is 1.

So why warn about an `==` where the operands are a bool and an integer?  Well, first of all because `151==true`, if you eyeball it, looks like it ought to be true (because 151 is a "true" value) but - as noted above - it's not.  It's a likely source of error, so that merits a warning.  More generally you're directly comparing two different types where the implicit conversion may not be obvious / may have non-obvious consequences.

Comment: On the other hand, I could imagine a situation where recoding it as `true == bool(151)` might be at least valid code (especially if you replace `151` with a variable), but even then it's probably a sign that something could be done more cleanly...

Comment: `bool` can only be `true` or `false`, nothing else without invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes... for better or worse this is the confusion of taking a language with a flexible application of boolean operators and sticking a `bool` type in it.  `if( 151 )` is perfectly well defined in spite of @Ics's observation, and its interpretation clarifies that 151 is a logically true value...

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger  The problem is that the language requires that comparisons be perform with both operands of the same type (after promotions).  The bool value is converted to an integer not the integer to the bool.  So the compiler is seeing `if (1==151)`

Comment: @RichardCritten - In your opinion the problem is that comparisons have to be of like type?  I disagree.  The problem is that they bool type contradicts the logic idioms that C (and therefore C++) historically used.  I'm not sure what part of this makes you think I don't know what the compiler sees; if you were to read my answer you'd note that I already called that out.